# Hackerrank problem: Find the runner-up score

Tags: python

This is what I am trying:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
max = -101
secondmax = -101
for a in arr:
    
    if max < a:
        max = a
    elif max > a and a > secondmax:
        secondmax = a
    
        
print(secondmax)
```

The result does not work. One of them was like: 1.  10  2. 5555555556

But I want to try it my way, which is what is shown as code above.

Comment: Why do you think your code doesn’t work? Did you try to use a debugger to step through it?

Comment: Don't "shadow" built-in functions such as *max*

Comment: What should the output be for an input of 1 2 2 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is not correct because the `elif` clause, which is the second part of your *if-statement*, it does not run if your first part is `True`, and that is why [secondmax] value does not get update. For example the [first element] of some test case was expected to become [secondmax] in result - but this [first element] got assigned to [maximum] value variable instead, and was lost being replaced by next [maximum] value on next iterations, which is not what we want.
And let me change that variable name 'max' to another name like 'm' or 'maximum' to avoid name clashing with built-in function `max` for better readabilty and neat code.
So might be this code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    arr = map(int, input().split())
maximum = -101
secondmax = -101
for a in arr:
    
    if maximum < a:
        secondmax = maximum 
        maximum = a
    if secondmax < a and a < maximum:
        secondmax = a

print(secondmax)
```

Here now if the new maximum value is found, the [secondmax] value gets update first. And with the second *if-statement* we handle test cases where the second maximum element is placed after the first maximum in the test sequence.

Answer (score 1):

When handling `if max < a`, you forgot to update `secondmax`. e.g.

```
if max < a:
    max, secondmax = a, max
```

To make this logic a bit easier, consider popping out the first two values immediately. This avoids needing to guess lower bounds for your operation. You can assert that there are at least two items (or handle the error however the problem statement requests you to).

Then I would clean up the variable names to make this easier to read:

```
def find_runner_up(arr):
    if len(arr) < 2:
        raise Exception
    largest, runner_up = max(arr[:2]), min(arr[:2])

    for current in arr[2:]:
        if current > largest:
            largest, runner_up = current, largest
        elif current > runner_up:
            runner_up = current

    return runner_up
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the list and return the penultimate value.

Like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input() # this is a stupid Hackerrank feature that's completely unnecessary for Python solutions
    values = input()
    lst = [int(v) for v in values.split()]
    assert len(lst) > 1
    print(sorted(lst)[-2])
```

If you prefer not to use the built-in *sorted()* function then:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    input() # this is a stupid Hackerrank feature that's completely unnecessary for Python solutions
    values = input()

    x = y = float("-inf")

    for v in map(int, values.split()):
        if v > y:
            x, y = y, v
        elif v > x:
            x = v

    print(x)
```

Comment: The question is likely aimed at writing code which makes this operation efficient, probably more similar to the `max` builtin. This is also what I would do for small inputs. But if we're going for code-golf: `sorted(map(int, input().split()))[-2]`

Comment: OP is clearly confused. Proposing a one-liner (which is 100% functionally correct) will only serve to bemuse him/her further - hence my step-by-step approach

Comment: Similarly, suggesting to call a builtin like `sorted` is not likely the intended solution for a novice. It skips the interesting parts of the problem. The educational moment here, would be to explain why this approach has downsides.